# Is it possible to configure GitHub Action workflow runs to delete automatically after some time?

Tags: github-actions

I have a lot of workflow runs. And though they are not bothering me, I would like to delete them because of the first principle of [lean software development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lean_software_development#Eliminate_waste) (eliminating waste).

However, I can't find anything in UI to bulk delete them. I also can't find a configuration to configure them to automatically delete after some time.

Is it possible to set the to automatically delete after some time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you go to repository **Settings -> Actions** there is a section **Artifact and log retention** where you can configure after how long the logs will be removed.

Comment: thank you. That's a good option. But it seems that it has bugs. Because the default value is 90 days which means 3 months. But I can see that my logs exist from 6 months ago.

Comment: @HosseinFallah did you find any way to delete it automatically?

Comment: @BambamDeo, no I didn't. Shame on GitHub.

Comment: This only remove logs and artifacts. Run are kept.

Answer (score 1):

I use this script. Save it as **deleteWorkflowRuns.sh** in your project folder.

```
org=<yourOrganizationOrUsername>
repo=<yourRepoNameAsInTheURL>

# Get workflow IDs with status "disabled_manually"
workflow_ids=($(gh api repos/$org/$repo/actions/workflows | jq '.workflows[] | select(.["state"] | contains("disabled_manually")) | .id'))

for workflow_id in "${workflow_ids[@]}"
do
  echo "Listing runs for the workflow ID $workflow_id"
  run_ids=( $(gh api repos/$org/$repo/actions/workflows/$workflow_id/runs --paginate | jq '.workflow_runs[].id') )
  for run_id in "${run_ids[@]}"
  do
    echo "Deleting Run ID $run_id"
    gh api repos/$org/$repo/actions/runs/$run_id -X DELETE >/dev/null
  done
done
```

Procedure:

1. Github Actions page: Disable the workflow whose runs you want to delete
2. Your local machine: Run the script.
3. Github Actions page: Check that all workflow runs were deleted.
4. Github Actions page: Enable the workflow again.

Comment: Does not iterate over each page.